# why it's showing error after showing the result?

Tags: c

i have made a program for finding prime factor of any number with the help of recursion.On compiling the program compiler is showing no type of error or warning and it's showing correct result also but problem is that after showing the result compile is showing a error something like " primere.exe is stop working". ( primere is my program's name.Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int prime(int, int);
int main()
{
    int num, i = 2;
    printf("enter the number:\t");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    prime(num , i);
    getch();
}
int prime(int num, int i)
{
    int j = 2;
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;
    if (num % i == 0)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
        prime(num / i, j);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (num % i != 0)
    {
        prime(num, i + 1);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some notes first: Indent your code! this is barely readable. Also `void main()` is wrong in C, where did you get that from?

Comment: it is showing errow with int main() too.

Comment: Long story short, you cannot solve this problem with recursion because it requires many more levels of recursion than the platform can support.

Comment: That does not change the fact that `void main` is not proper C, it is a bad habit that you should not pick up (from wherever)

Comment: Same with conio.h, a non-standard header. I'm guessing Turbo C compiler?

Comment: @remyabel i'm using CodeBlocks

Comment: CodeBlocks is an [IDE](http://www.codeblocks.org/features) and can use different compilers. The header file(s) you use are independent of it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `if(num==0)` to `if(num==0 || num==1)`

Because your variable `num` does not come to `0` at any point.
And the loop would not end at all.

Example: if you take 12 as num

It will execute `prime(12, 2);` and it print 2.

Then it will execute `prime(12/2, 2);`

Then it will print 2 and execute `prime(6/2, 2);`

Then it will check if condition `3%2==0` which is `false`.

Then it will execute the `else` statement which is `prime(3, 3);`
This will print `3` and execute `prime(3/3, 2);`

Which will then again execute `prime(1, 2);` and Here it will recursively call `prime(1, 2);` and this will continue forever.

Comment: ohh...that works awesome! can you explain it in more brief please.

Comment: @user4156958 Your program is suffering from a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) because your recursive function never terminates.

Comment: seems confusing how it is not terminating i mean if we take a example 12 then this statement if(num==0) will be true after printing 2 2 3 and after that it should be terminated.

Comment: @user4156958 , 3/3 != 0. It is 1

Comment: oh that was a stupid mistake by me..thankyou for pointing out tha.Thankyou! :)